# What Marge says about Giant's Causeway?

Tags: spoken-english

I have seen the following video, where Marge and Family go to the Giant's Causeway. I don't fully understand what she says, even if I slow the playback speed. This is the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nmpu-ondyFg

This is what I think she says - I don't understand the words in bold part.:

The Giant's Causeway, is the result of a vulcanic eruption.
Well kids, **isn't dare and formational fant?**

Please, can you help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Marge says, *"Well, kids, isn't that an informational fact?"*

https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=the-simpsons&episode=s20e14

It is an example of a redundant statement, which, to me, belies the nature of Marge's character.  She is as disinterested in the history as her children, but feels she must *encourage* their interest so that they have a chance of becoming "better" people.

Comment: yes, thanks, it's clear now. Also the link is a very useful resource! However listening again, I always hear "fant" instead of "fact", event if the word "fant" doesn't exists.